# How to read integer command line arguments in Python?

Tags: python, string, input, command-line-arguments

I have been trying the following, as suggested by many post, but I am still getting

> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gap_interval.py'`. What am I missing?

```
import sys 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 4
    a = []
    for i in sys.argv:
        print int(i.strip())
```

Comment: `gap_interval.py` is not a string.  It is also part of sys.argv which it's telling you.

Comment: right, it's sys.argv[0]. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to skip sys.argv[0], which is the script's name:

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Python `sys.argv` always contains the filename as the first argument:

```
>>> python test.py 1 2 3
>>> sys.argv
['test.py', '1', '2', '3']
```

If you want to convert it to `int`, you can do:

```
nums = map(int, sys.argv[1:])

>>> nums
[1,2,3]
```